# Why to use square brackets [ ] when using custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I understand destructuring that it unpacks values from array into variables and using square brackets in useState means it is returning two values in that array, first one is value and second one is function that is used to change that value,
But I see [] when using custom hook, and It does not make any sense to me , Can anyone please explain me why variable [breeds] has square brackets around it. it is declared under useState.

```
    const ANIMALS = ["bird", "cat", "dog", "rabbit", "reptile"];



export const SearchParams = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
    const [animal, setAnimal] = useState('');
    const [breed, setBreed] = useState('')
    const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
    const [breeds] = useBreedList(animal); 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    requestPets();
},[animal])

  async function requestPets() {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://pets-v2.dev-apis.com/pets?animal=${animal}&location=${location}&breed=${breed}`
    );
    const json = await res.json(); 
    console.info('json is '+JSON.stringify(json))
    setPets(json.pets);
    console.warn("pets are " + JSON.stringify(pets));
  }
    return (
      <div className="search-params">
        

        <form>
          <label htmlFor="location">
            Location
            <input
              id="location"
              value={location}
              placeholder="Location"
              onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="animal">
            Animal
            <select
              id="animal"
              value={animal}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setAnimal(e.target.value);
                setBreed("");
              }}
              onBlur={(e) => {
                setAnimal(e.target.value);
                setBreed("");
              }}
            >
              <option />
              {ANIMALS.map((animal) => (
                <option key={animal}>{animal}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="breed">
            Breed
            <select
              id="breed"
              value={breed}
              onChange={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
              disabled={breeds.length === 0}
            >
              <option />
              {breeds.map((breed) => (
                <option key={breed}>{breed}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        {pets.map((pet) => (
          <Pet
            name={pet.name}
            animal={pet.animal}
            breed={pet.breed}
            key={pet.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

This is custom hook

```
    const localCache = {};

export const useBreedList = (animal) => {
    const [breedList, setBreedList] = useState([]);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState("unloaded"); 

    useEffect(() => {
      
        if (!animal) {
            setBreedList([])

        } else if (localCache[animal]) {
            setBreedList(localCache[animal])
            
        } else {
            requestBreedList();
        }

        async function requestBreedList() {
           
            setBreedList([]);
            setStatus("loading");
            const res = await fetch(
                `https://pets-v2.dev-apis.com/breeds?animal=${animal}`
            )
            const json = await res.json();
            
            localCache[animal] = json.breeds || [] 
            
            setBreedList(localCache[animal]);
            setStatus("loaded");
        }
    }, [animal]);

    return [breedList, status];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me too. The only advantage is that it's shorter to rename, but I would use an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain me why variable `[breeds]` has square brackets around it. it is declared under `useState`.

Because it's destructuring the result of calling `useBreedList`, which (like `useState`) returns **two** pieces of information, wrapped up in a tuple (a fixed-length array):

```
export const useBreedList = (animal) => {
    // ...
    return [breedList, status]; // <=================================
};
```

Since they're returning two pieces of information, the people writing `useBreedList` had the same choice that the people writing `useState` did:

1. Return a tuple (fixed-length array) people can destructure into variables they control the names of
2. Return an object with (say) `breedlist` and `status` properties

It's easier to control your own variable names when using the hook when the hook uses a tuple (#1) rather than an object (#2) — and indeed, the code you've quoted is using `breeds` rather than `breedList`. If the hook did this:

```
return { breedList, status };
```

...then the quoted code would have had to do this to use the name `breeds` instead:

```
const { breedList: breeds } = useBreedList(animal);
```

That said, this hook is really specific, I wouldn't have been surprised to find it written using a (non-array) object instead, and for code using it to consistently use `const { breedList, status } = useBreedList(animal);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn’t support functions that return multiple values. However, you can wrap multiple values into an array or an object and return the array or the object.

Use `destructuring` assignment syntax to unpack values from the array, or properties from objects.